# How to resolve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am mUrthy,I am writing below selenium script , when I am trying to execute scripts i am getting error please see the below script and error. Any one provide better solution for this. I am using latest versions for this.

**Script:**

package TestProject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver;
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://GeckoDriver/geckodriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/");
}
```

}
**Error:**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Duplicate local variable driver

```
at TestProject.FirstTestCase.main(FirstTestCase.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared driver twice, use like this;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
"C://GeckoDriver/geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/");
}
```